# Cinder + FreeImage + XCode

Tags: xcode, linker, freeimage, cinder

I am working on a project that uses Cinder for graphics, and for image loading, we are using FreeImage mainly for loading HDR images.

It is all working fine under windows, but now I am trying to build an OSX version I am hitting a snag.

First I tried to download and build FreeImage, but the makefiles are hopelessly outdated and do not work. I managed to fudge them and build the library, but when adding to xcode it didn't seem to link. The error was that the library was ignored because it was built with a different architecture. (I couldn't figure out how to fix this, but it is an option to go back to if all else fails).

Anyway, my next attempt was to use macports to install and build FreeImage. This all worked without error and I was able to include the library in my project.

However, the problem now it that I get many std linking errors. After searching around, **it seems my problem is that freeimage was built with libstdc++, but cinder complains if I dont build my project with C++11**.

So, is there any way of fixing this? Can I modify the make files macports uses to build freeimage? Or is there some other sneaky way? Any suggestions appreciated.

Sorry if this question is a bit parochial, but in my searches I have seen others with similar problems (but unfortunately few answers).